# Find records with more than one ActiveRecord HABTM Association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got two models, joined by a Has and Belongs To Many join table. Lets call these models User and Event.  The majority of Users have 0 events, while few have one or more.  I want to do something like:

User.find(:all, :joins => :events, :conditions => ["***'Something that count the events'*** > ?"], 0)

The problem is, I'm not sure how to select only users that have 1 or more associated events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer:

```
User.find(:all, :joins => :events, :select => 'DISTINCT `users`.*')
```

Basically, the `users`.* restricts the result set to just the users table, and the DISTINCT keyword makes sure each user is only returned once.

Comment: This does not solve the problem for a case where you want more than N results, and not just 1.  Can anyone offer an AR way to do it, other than just raw SQL?